# Is it possible to set font style of the text which is going to be recognized?

Tags: android, firebase, text-recognition, firebase-mlkit

Is it possible to set font style of the text which is going to be recognized?

I am implementing an Android application to scan documents with the fixed font. The problem I am experiencing is the incorrect detection 0-digit (the font uses slashed-zero) and in 90% of the cases detected as 8.

Comment: Are you using the on-device API or the cloud API?

Comment: I am using on-device API

Comment: Thanks... we will consider adding it or updating the model to handle this case in our upcoming releases!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you cannot set the font style of the text in the current API of ML Kit. We will explore if exposing such an API can help the model detect these accurately.

The main underlying issue can also be addressed by updating the model to handle such images. We will definitely try to address the issue in the coming releases.